# Which OSM2PO method returns segment speed?

Tags: osm2po

In OSM2PO, RoutingResultSegment has a getH() method - what values does it return? I was looking for a method that returns kmh, similarly to what is stored in the DB, but it doesn't seem like getH() returns that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method which returns the speed. As the graph is already prepared for routing, it only needs to know Time or Distance.
But you can regain the speed by calculating round(getKm() / getH())